# How to delete files starting with # using "rm #*"?

Tags: shell, wildcards, rm

In bash, I want to delete files starting with a `#`. I tried `rm #*`, but got message: `rm: missing operand`.

So how to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The octothorpe (`#`), or pound sign, is a comment character, described in the [POSIX grammar here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_03) as saying:

> If the current character is a '#', it and all subsequent characters up to, but excluding, the next <newline> shall be discarded as a comment. The <newline> that ends the line is not considered part of the comment.

So you need to quote or escape the pound sign so that it is not interpreted as a comment:

```
rm '#'*
```

or

```
rm "#"*
```

or

```
rm \#*
```

Answer (score 3):

While the `#` starts a comment, it only does so at the start of a word. So prefixing a path, like `./` for current directory, also works to disable it.

```
rm ./#*
```

Incidentally, prefixing `./` is also one of the two ways to prevent file names starting with a dash
 (`-like-this`) being interpreted as options to the command.

Answer (score 3):

If your shell is `bash`, you can disable the use of `#` as a comment character *in an interactive shell* with

```
shopt -u interactive_comments
```

With this shell option cleared,

```
rm #*
```

should work as you initially expected it, without the need to escape the `#`.

Answer (score 0):

depending on the shell setup  you might use

```
rm \#file
```

or

```
rm '#file'
```

or if it is a special character interpreted and displayed as # then

```
rm ?file
```

could work

Comment: All of those could not work, error: `rm: cannot remove ‘#rm’: No such file or directory`, `rm: cannot remove ‘#rm’: No such file or directory`, `rm: cannot remove ‘?rm’: No such file or directory`.   By the way, I am using the cluster.

Comment: @lanselibai - he probably meant `rm \#*`... the point is, you only have to escape the `#` so that bash [doesn't ignore it.](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Comments.html)